"Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker
Since recently (7 Dec 2024?), the "Newest Questions" tab (/questions?tab=Newest) now showing the last active user instead of the asker.



This applies to every site.
I'm not sure if this is intended or a bug. If it's intended, could we know the reason for the change? If it's a bug, there was a similar issue back then in 2013, though it only affected the mobile view (when the desktop view and mobile view were separated).

On [math.meta.se]: question orders "Newest" and "Active" working strangely. I did not find other posts about this issue.

This is a bug.  I noticed this yesterday on a few sites as well.  Also, if you select a tag, like "discussion", then all the questions in the list show the asker, as expected.

Ditto here, sites and their METAs, starting yesterday.

You can use is:q in search as a workaround

Was I correct in concluding that the "Newest" ordering really does put the questions in order of time asked,  but now not necessarily showing the asker and the time asked in the lower right field?

@WillJagy yeah, the ordering is still correct, only the user info is not as usual.

I hope it is a bug and that it is fixed.

@Buffy It appears not to be fixed from here, then it is Sunday, not a work day.

@emanresuA it isn't?

@W.O., I should have said I hope it gets fixed. I'm also seeing most recent answer (at Academia) as well as latest edit.

Seeing this here and in SU, but not SO. But I have a complex search filter in SO, so per @toolic comment above, that may be why.

@JeffZeitlin see my previous comment.

@VLAZ - That's what I see in SU and Meta and pretty much everything else, but I don't see it in SO. I have a complex search filter set for SO, though, thus my previous comment.

@JeffZeitlin when I was writing my comment, yours didn't have that detail in it. Yes, appears to work on pages other than the one that the question mentions and shows. But the same is true for every other site - on MSE, click on a tag and go to Newest. It will only show the asker and the creation date. But go to SO to /questions and sort by newest and you will see the last action for each post. As my screenshot demonstrates.

I wonder if this is related to their quick patch to hide Answer Bot activity

@Jeremy doubt it, as the AB is specific to one site, doubt they made some cross network change to hide it.

Looks like it has been fixed as early as 7 hours ago.
